Flutter Bloc - how to handle form related state
I'm new to Flutter Bloc, I'm handling customer related bloc where there can be following states CustomerLoaded, CustomerLoading, CustomerAddLoader and CustomerInvalidForm
CustomerLoaded - this state holds customer list
CustomerLoading - this state is emitted when fetching customers from backend (API Call)
CustomerAddLoader - this state is emitted when adding customer
CustomerInvalidForm - this state is emitted if there is validation related error in customer adding form
the problem is that if I emit CustomerInvalidForm state (due to form validation), this state is shown across all screen where I'm displaying customer list, I wouldn't want to show such validation related state on customer list screen
basically when I emit CustomerInvalidForm state, CustomerLoaded state is no longer available on Customer List screen where I'm displaying all customers
how to handle such scenario?
Customer State Class
abstract class CustomerState {}

class CustomerInitialState extends CustomerState {}

class CustomerAddLoader extends CustomerState {}

class CustomerLoading extends CustomerState{}

class CustomerLoaded extends CustomerState {
  final List<CustomerModel> customerList;

  CustomerLoaded({required this.customerList});
}

class CustomerError extends CustomerState {
  final String error;

  CustomerError({required this.error});
}

class CustomerInvalidForm extends CustomerState {
  String error;
  CustomerInvalidForm({required this.error});
}


Customer Bloc
class CustomerBloc extends Bloc<CustomerEvent, CustomerState> {
  final List<CustomerModel> _customerList = [];

  CustomerBloc() : super(CustomerInitialState()) {
    on<CustomerInitialEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(CustomerLoaded(customerList: _customerList));
    });
    on<AddCustomerEvent>((event, emit) async {
      CustomerModel customerModel = event.customerModel;
      if (customerModel.customerName.isEmpty) {
        emit(CustomerInvalidForm(error: 'Customer name is required')); // CustomerLoaded state is no longer available on customer list screen
      } else {
        emit(CustomerAddLoader());
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
        _customerList.add(customerModel);
        emit(CustomerLoaded(customerList: _customerList));
      }
    });
  }
}


